# Switching a velocity from one rigid body to another in unity

Tags: unity, physics, rigidbody

I have a set up where the ground and the player move with physics and a stationary camera.

I want the ground to move faster when the player is getting further away making it look that the player is moving faster without getting further away from the camera.

The way I first thought was to just add the player velocity to the ground velocity, since velocity doesn't care about mass, and set the player velocity to 0.

*On the player script:*

```cs
    public void MovePlayer(Vector3 force)
    {
        rb.AddForce(force, ForceMode.Force);
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (rb.position.z > 10)
        {
            PlatformManager.PlayerVelocity = rb.velocity.z;
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(rb.velocity.x, rb.velocity.y, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            PlatformManager.PlayerVelocity = 0;
        }
    }
```

*On the ground script:*

```cs
      //On the fixed update
            if (playerVelocity > 0)
            {
                rb.velocity = (Vector3.back * speedMultiplier) - new Vector3(0, 0, playerVelocity);
            }
            else
            {
                rb.velocity = Vector3.back * speedMultiplier;
            }
```

Although this way the player stops at the set limit, because in the next frame its velocity is 0 and the ground velocity is back to regular.

So how could I achieve this? Do I need to calculate manually the velocity that would result in the player movement (with the force in `MovePlayer`) and set it to the ground? I can't use the force on the ground due to its mass difference.

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you're trying to achieve from your question. You wrote "I want the ground to move faster" but weren't clear about how the ground is moving in relation to the player. From your code, it looks like you want the ground to move with the player on the Z axis, but without a better explanation or an animation, it's hard to guess how it looks now or how you want it to look.

Comment: The ground is moving on the opposite direction from the player, on the z axis.

Comment: And I said the "ground move faster (...) making it look like the player is moving faster" I can try to edit the question later but I believe its pretty clear. I need something like the player to be freezed on the z axis, while all its z axis velocity is transferred to the ground, on the opposite direction, making the player look that is moving faster while in reality is not moving

Comment: It is not "pretty clear". Is your game side-view? Top-down? Isometric? What does "without getting further away from the camera" mean? You don't want the player to get further from the camera?

Comment: My best wild guess is that you have a top-down game and are trying to fake a jump by moving the ground down instead of the player up. That seems like an overly complicated, confusing solution. Maybe you should move the camera with the player if you want to maintain the distance from the player to the camera.

Comment: I have my reasons to want to move the ground and keep the camera stationary, the game is 3D and the only concern here is the z axis, why does it matter the style of the game? 
and yes, i dont want the player to get to far from the camera, i want to "freeze" the player on the z axis if its getting too far from the camera and make the ground move in the opposite direction on the z axis. for who is playing this is just as if the camera is following the player. its just an internal mechanic to avoid large transform numbers.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the style of game because I can't think of any good reason why you would need to do what you want to do. There's no need to be difficult with people who are trying to help you. What do you mean by "large transform numbers"? Unless your character is jumping 100,000 units into the air, large transform numbers won't be an issue.

Comment: I am sorry you feel that way. In the game the issue would be the z axis (forward in unity). At first there is no issue but at some point will be.

Comment: It sounds to me like you're making an endless runner game and worried about loss of floating point precision when the player runs a long way from the origin. Saying so plainly will avoid a lot of this back-and-forth, and make it easier for readers to suggest existing Q&A about how to deal with this.

Comment: As I understood, Kevin didn't understand what I was asking, when he suggested I try other way I explained that it would cause such errors. I can edit the question to explicit mention the floating point precision. Maybe my question could be better explained but I shouldn't be questioned why I am making such attempt, unless clearly doesn't make sense, of course. I think its a legit question and I believe is a common practice to keep the player on the centre while moving the map. I'm open to accept any edit that would make the question more readable, assuming the focus stays the same.

Comment: I didn't understand what you were asking because you declined to provide any details. The six words "I'm making an endless runner game" would have avoided all of this confusion. As for why I questioned your approach: we frequently get questions where the poster is trying to do something really weird because they don't know the correct way to do it and are doing it in entirely the wrong way. In those cases, the best way to help is to _tell them the correct way to do it_, not help them do it the wrong way.

Comment: I gotta thanks you for your persistence. I dont know what is the difference between knowing if its a endless runner or what i explained on the question. Sorry I took so long to reach this point but I did answer your comments providing the information I thought was relevant. If endless runner doest, yes it is endless runner style. But the mechanics remain, the player moves little, the ground moves on the z axis toward the camera, if the player moves to much away from the camera on the z axis the ground speeds up and the player slows (although apparently its faster)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that DMGregory's guess that you're making an endless runner is correct, your question suddenly makes sense and is answerable.

I think you are going about this the wrong way. Currently, you are moving the player with forces, but want a way to transfer the velocity from the player to the ground. As you've already discovered, this is somewhat of a headache.

I'd suggest not using forces for this, and controlling velocity manually. You would track the player's current speed separately from the physics engine. Then, you could offset the player on the Z-axis based on the current speed.

```
public class Player : MonoBehavior {
    [SerializeField] private float currentSpeed;
    [SerializeField] private float speedToDistanceFactor = .1f;
    [SerializeField] private float maxDistance = 10f;
    [SerializeField] private float collisionSlowdownFactor = 1f;
    public float CurrentSpeed { 
        get => currentSpeed; 
        set {
            currentSpeed = Mathf.Max(value, 0); //don't allow negative speed
        }
    }

    //move us further away from the camera when we're going faster
    void Update() {
        var pos = transform.position;
        pos.z = CurrentSpeed * speedToDistanceFactor;
        pos.z = Mathf.Clamp(pos.z, 0, maxDistance);
        transform.position = pos;
    }

    //slow down when we collide with a GO tagged "Obstacle", based on
    //the mass of the object we hit.
    //you will probably need to change/customize this logic
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Obstacle")) {
            CurrentSpeed -= collision.body.mass * collisionSlowdownFactor;
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the `OnCollisionEnter()` function includes some basic logic for slowing the player down when they collide with an object. You can customize or replace this logic as needed.

Then the ground would move according to the current speed, for example:

```
public class Ground : MonoBehavior {
    [SerializeField] private Player player;
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody body;

    void Awake() { Assert.IsNotNull(player); }

    void FixedUpdate() {
        if (body != null) {
            body.velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, -player.CurrentSpeed);
        } else {
            transform.Translate(0, 0, -player.CurrentSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

With this simple approach, we have one key value - `player.CurrentSpeed`. The player's z-position, and the movement of the ground, are both derived from this value. It's very simple and doesn't require transferring velocity from one object to another under certain conditions.

Comment: I can only try to do this tomorrow, but will this emulate physics force? Speeding the player according to its mass? And moving on the update without the deltaTime wont create issues? Btw I am usic physics because i have collisions, this looks like wont be effective against higger speed collisions.

Comment: My suggestion is not to use forces. You can reduce the player speed when a collision occurs; I'll update my answer with an example. `deltaTime` is not necessary in the Player `Update()` function because the position is proportional to the player's speed. I'm not sure what you mean by "won't be effective against higher speed collisions". Are you referring to Continuous Collision Detection (CCD)?

Comment: I will have to try this method to see if it works  as I intended, btw the obstacle should be "infinite" mass, the only mass I care is the player, that should affect the acceleration. And yes I am using CCD but I had a lot of trouble setting up a reliable collision set up since in most settings the player would "teleport" through the obstacles at reasonably low speeds. And changing position through `transform.position` seems that it will pass right through the obstacles

Comment: @Barreto You can rewrite the OnCollisionEnter() to slow down the player using whatever formula best suits your game. As far as moving the player, you can of course use `rigidbody.MovePosition()` instead of `transform.position`. This is a simple example, not a complete ready-to-ship solution.

Comment: I am very thankful for your efforts but after some thought and rest on the issue I have solved in a rather simple way I will post an answer when I have some time in case you are curious. This answers approach doesn't help much, since it changes the dynamics of the game and avoids the scenario proposed on the question.